# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x978fdffc (code=2), thread 26545

Tags: android, webview

In my context, my activity has a webview which will load news content( article) from somewhere on the internet. After moving to other screens several times, I got that

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x978fdffc (code=2), thread 26545

before my app got crashed. No other information from stack trace that seems to be helpful in this case.

Comment: In the article, are there bitmaps shown?

Comment: Can you please add more of the log message? Specifically the 10-15 lines below that error.